# 'Email inquiries from employers' counter increases every time when somebody sends a message

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

There is a strange behaviour on careers.stackoverflow.com.

When somebody sends a new message the counter 'Email inquiries from employers' increases.

It seems that it must be only increased for a new contact request but not for an every new message.

Here is my state:

[image]

I have only 2 message threads (e.g. 2 contacts) but the counter shows 12 email inquiries.

Is it a feature?

Comment: I'll look into this shortly.

Answer (score 3):

The fix for this is on it's way out now.  The cache for old values on this is 6 hours or a new message, so it might be this afternoon (EST) before you see the updated numbers.  For the record, we are **not** including threads which were started with the "Ask this employer a question" feature.